# mezzanine multi tenancy, gunicorn, nginx configuration

Tags: django, nginx, multi-tenant, gunicorn, mezzanine

I hope this goes here and not to server fault, since I think it's more a mezzanine/django issue.

I'm trying to make use of [mezzanines multi tenancy](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/multi-tenancy.html) to serve different themes to each domain.

I start gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8000 -b 127.0.0.1:8001 domain1_domain2.wsgi:application

to bind 2 ports for each theme/domain.

settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'domain1.dev',  
    'domain2.dev.', 
    "127.0.0.1:8000",
    "127.0.0.1:8001",
    "*",
]

HOST_THEMES = [
    ('domain1.dev', 'theme1'), 
    ('domain2.dev', 'theme2'),
    ('127.0.0.1:8000', 'theme1'), 
    ('127.0.0.1:8001', 'theme2'), 
]
```

nginx

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name domain1.dev;

    location /static {
        root /home/david/domain1_domain2/domain1_domain2/domain1;   
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8000;  
   }

}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name domain2.dev;

    location /static {
        root /home/david/domain1_domain2/domain1_domain2/domain2;   
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8001;  
   }

}
```

hosts

```
127.0.0.1       www.domain1.dev
127.0.0.1       domain1.dev

127.0.0.1       www.domain2.dev
127.0.0.1       domain2.dev
```

http://127.0.0.1:8000 / www.domain1.dev correctly display theme1. But http://127.0.0.1:8001 / www.domain2.dev display theme1, too, and not theme2 as expected.

Can this done with mulit tenancy? What I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Are you typing in `http://www.domain2.dev/` or `http://domain2.dev/`? If the former, then perhaps you should change your `server_name` to `server_name domain2.dev www.domain2.dev;` It could be the case that because Nginx didn't recognise the `www` part, it's defaulting to your first server block (although `default_server` is usually specified for this)

Comment: Ok, I added it to server_name, then tried with proxy_pass http://www.google.com and it goes to google, so it goes to the second server block.

Comment: Was it the outcome that you expected?

Comment: I mean, it makes no difference, http://127.0.0.1:8001/ already shows the wrong theme, the problem persists.

Comment: theme2 should show on http://127.0.0.1:8001/  not theme1